# Masking Text Websockets?

Tags: node.js, websocket

As pertinent to this module for nodeJS:
https://github.com/websockets/ws

Sending regular text data is as followed:

```
ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});
```

And for sending binary data:

```
ws.on('open', function open() {
  var array = new Float32Array(5);

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i] = i / 2;
  }

  ws.send(array, { binary: true, mask: true });
});
```

Is it possible to mask the text data? Or is masking only possible while sending binary data?

Answer (score 1):

From the `ws` README (emphasis mine):

> Setting `mask`, as done for the send options above, will cause the data to be masked according to the WebSocket protocol. *The same option applies for text data.*

So, although I haven't tried this, it seems that the answer is yes.

Comment: Hm.. sorry for my late response. I tried `ws.send('hello', { binary: false, mask: true });` and it shows it [unmasked](http://i.gyazo.com/1304eadcddb5b950a749b4012355f1d9.png), any idea?  Hmmmm...

Comment: @NiCkNewman The browser is almost certainly doing the unmasking for you.  Have you tried using Wireshark or something like that to look at bytes on the wire?  Also, why are you masking?  Masking is only required in the client->server direction.

Comment: Yeah, wireshark shows it unmasked as well.  I am just trying to add a small layer of 'protection' if you will, to hinder people looking at my frames. Without them ofcourse, you know installing wireshark, and actually looking at the payload. But, I'm just trying to add more layers the script kiddie will have to go through so they will stop. If that makes sense.  Although, everything is secure serverside within my gameserver, I just feel weird having my frames so easily readable when someone can just hit F-12.

Comment: If someone is dedicated enough to read my frames/payload data, I want them to go through wireshark and look at my JS code, etc to find out how to decode the data themselves. (Or if it's binary, do the conversation themselves) That's what I ultimately want, I want the end-user to have a pain in the ass to read my frames so they don't attempt or even think of doing anything fishy. 

I can never ultimately stop them, but I want to make the mission for them to get there as hard as possible.

Comment: Masking isn't intended for use in that direction, so the browser might have already signaled it doesn't support it or something like that.  Even if you could get this to work, the browser is going to do the unmasking for the user.  I would suggest taking a different route if obscurity is your goal (although I would also suggest setting it up so obscurity isn't necessary).